# Where does the output of the `\showthe` command go to under AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex

Consider the following LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\showthe\parindent
\end{document}
```

According to p. 215 of Donald Knuth's *The TeXbook*, 20th revised printing (Addison-Wesley 1991)

> TeX's primitive command '\showthe' will display on your terminal exactly what '\the' would produce in an expanded definition; the expansion is preceded by '>' and followed by a period. For example, '\showthe\parindent' will display
>     `> 20.0pt.`
>   if the plain TeX paragraph indentation is being used.

Where is the output of the `\showthe` primitive directed to by AUCTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from LaTeX compilation should appear in a buffer named `*/path/to/source.tex output*`. Using your example I see on my system:

> ...
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
>   > 17.0pt.
>   l.56 \showthe \parindent
>   ...